# genetic algorithm for TSP - library in python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I was trying to find the shortest path in TSP using genetic algorithm. Is there any library in the python for this problem? Is there any code for this problem? Is there any steps or hint for how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm attaching a tsp solution finder using genetic algo repo from github, please look at the source and use it
https://github.com/maoaiz/tsp-genetic-python